# Save changes made by content editable on any website

Tags: javascript, php, contenteditable

The following code allows any website to be completely editable temporarily:

```
document.body.contentEditable = "true";
```

If I want to save the settings made to a particular website using this method, how can I achieve this using Javascript and if needed PHP, so that next time I visit this URL, the website updates automatically with the settings made. Is this even possible? Is there an extension already available?

Comment: You mean using a userscript?

Comment: You can use [`localStorage`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) to save data. The trigger can be when `contentEditable` gets disabled.

Comment: Save the content into **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** and upon page load, restore the `localStorage` value (if there is one), or load the default content if not.

Comment: While I've provided my opinion,I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are many ways to do this and the user would be better off Googling "off-line storage".

Comment: @yuvrajprogrammer save the data inside the `<div>`, not the entire page

Comment: But please tell exactly how to save the settings to local storage.  What will be the key and the value of the item to be stored?

Comment: You decide what the key name should be and what data to store. Click the link in my comment and you'll be taken to the documentation.

Comment: key "data" value "<div></div>"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way you can do this using vanilla JS.

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrd86n2v/4/) since StackOverflow doesn't allow `localStorage` to be executed on the website as a security feature.

**How it works:**

1. Using `window.onload = function() {...}`, check if `'content'` key
   exists in `localStorage`
2. If it does, load the data into `<div class="content">`
3. Upon pressing `Edit` button, `contentEditable` is toggled
4. Here you can use any method to save the data. I used `content.contentEditable === 'false'` to save the `innerHTML` data to `'content'` key.

**To Note:** `localStorage` is saved in your browser locally, use databases or anything similar to display edits to all viewers.

---

```js
// Load content onload if it exists in localStorage
window.onload = function() {
 if(localStorage.getItem('content')) {
  document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('content');
  }
}

let editBtn = document.querySelector('#edit_content');
let content = document.querySelector('.content');

editBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Toggle contentEditable on button click
 content.contentEditable = !content.isContentEditable;
  
  // If disabled, save text
  if(content.contentEditable === 'false') {
   localStorage.setItem('content', content.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<br>
<button id="edit_content">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Answer basically salvaged from the comments, if it was here would be easier for people to read]

Save the data inside the `<div>` (not the entire page) into a `localStorage`. You can save when the `document.body.contentEditable` is disabled. You can then re-load it into the html when the page reloads.

Comment: But how to I do that automatically?

Comment: You just put it in the js.

Comment: Read the documentation for `localStorage`

Comment: Please give me exact link to follow

Comment: @yuvrajprogrammer I have already provided you with the exact link to follow in the comments below your question. Click the `localStorage` blue link. We can't help you if you won't slow down and read what we're saying.

Comment: @yuvrajprogrammer Then what do you need help with?

Comment: @SheshankS. If I deleted a <div> or <table> element on a website, how to save that particular setting in local storage?

Comment: Just save the html in the localstorage

Comment: key = 'changes' , value = html ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173218/discussion-between-yuvraj-programmer-and-sheshank-s).