# How do you record changes when activating document.body.contentEditable

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to record the changes that have happened when using either:

```
document.designmode = true
```

or

```
document.contenteditable = true
```

With specific reference to if the information shown on the website is retrieved from a database. Also, thank you in advanced for the help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'record' changes? Do you want to store and do something with these changes or just display them on the screen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876234/save-changes-made-by-content-editable-on-any-website

Comment: the changes would be stored ina database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They key is that the edited content will be available in the dom and can be accessed via dom methods any time. It is on the part of the developer to design a system which can read the changes, perform caparison and sand save it in the back end if necessary.

```js
function addRevision() {

  let revContainer = document.getElementById('revisions');
  
  revContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  revContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Revision'));

  revContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  revContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('editable').innerHTML))


}
```

```html
<div id="editable" contentEditable="true">

<p> Hello Editbale (change me)</p>

</div>

<input type="button" value="Add Revision" onClick="addRevision()">

<div id="revisions">


</div>
```

Comment: within react.js would this then have to be done through refs?

Comment: I have no particular experience with React. However, I believe that any framework offers reading the content - and any of those methods can be used to get the changed content.